# In Android how do I get a socket to connect to a specified servlet?

Tags: android, sockets, tomcat, servlets

In Android I need to make a socket or some kind of consistent connection to a servlet I made in tomcat. I was told when making a socket you have to give it an IP address instead of an URL. Problem is that normally to access it I'd go to  [IP]/papon/[more address]

and just the IP alone isn't hitting it.

So how do I get it to hit that specific servlet or call a get from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to let the server know what path you are requesting.  After opening the socket try writing to the output stream:

```
GET /papon/[more address] HTTP/1.0
```

Followed by two newline characters